# Extra white space when get visible content of UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uigraphicscontext

There is a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` which user can scale it down and up and then save it:

[image]

The area under the **navigation bar** and top of the **tab bar** is `UIScrollView` frame.

When user hits **Done**, image will be save in camera roll. It's what saved there (Photos App):
[image]

I have no idea what is this empty space in the saved image.

It's my code to save the image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
            let rect = CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
            self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
            let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

What I want to save is exactly the visible region of `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `CGContextTranslateCTM()` to translate the rectangle:

```
    let screenRect: CGRect = scrollView.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size)
    let ctx: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,0,-scrollView.frame.origin.y)
    UIColor.blackColor().set()
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect)
        view.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```